# Interpreting ANN results -> MSE, MAE and undisplayed epochs results

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

Im trainning an ANN model with just a few samples (10) to predict 45 targets with 38 inputs. I cannot figure iut why the results per epoch are not being displayed, any idea?
Also, the overall MAE and MSE I get is 0.5252 and 0.6234, respectively. I'm not sure how to interpretate such values as my dataset was scaled. 
My code:

```
input_size = 37
output_size = 45
hidden_layer_size = 3
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_layer_size, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_layer_size, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(output_size, activation='linear') 
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_absolute_error', metrics=['MeanAbsoluteError','mse'])

batch_size = 10
max_epochs = 20
callback=tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=2)
model.fit(train_inputs, 
          train_targets, 
          batch_size=10, 
          epochs=max_epochs, 
          verbose=0,
          callbacks=[callback],
          validation_data=(validation_inputs, validation_targets)
          )
```

**Out:** `<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x25bad7cff48>`
**In:** `test_loss= model.evaluate(test_inputs, test_targets)`
**Out:** `2/2 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/sample - loss: 0.5252 - mean_absolute_error: 0.5252 - mean_squared_error: 0.6234`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass verbose=2 in model.fit() to get results for every epoch.
MAE and MSE values depend on your data. MSE is more sensitive to large error values, in general high MSE means you probably get large errors for few of your samples, while high MAE means you are getting smaller error values, but for many of your samples.

Comment: So a high MAE is not very critical but still, as lower its value, the better, right? My inputs values vary between -2.5 and 2.5 and my target values within a range of -8.5 to 8.5, by the way. Would you say, the model is acceptable for predicting?

Comment: Both MAE and MSE should be as low as possible, ideally zero. I can't say whether your model is acceptable for predicting, because I don't know how much precise you expect it to be. Try testing it and see if results are acceptable for you.